# Is it possible to configure (really) global keyboard shortcut in Linux (like ctrl+alt+fN)?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I need kind of keyboard shortcut that works no matter it's locked desktop session, or it's TTY-console.
And this shortcut must call my script or command.
Is this possible without compiling custom kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have a demon program listen on the `/dev/input/eventX` that corresponds to your keyboard, and pick out whatever key combination you like, and execute a script or command on that.

I don't know any ready-made program that does this, however, you'll have to write your own. A relatively simple C program should do, but you can do it in any programming language you are familiar with.